How to truncate long tex with flex parent having min-width:0 and flex grandparent having flex-wrap: wrap?
I want the blue text ( element) which is inside a flex item to get truncated with ellipsis (...) if text is too long. To do so I have to add min-width:0 to the parent (.entity-container). You can click Toggle element min-width to see how adding min-width:0 affects the code. It adds the ellipsis but it breaks also the flex-wrap: wrap property of .monitored-entities grandparent. In other words flex-wrap: wrap acts like flex-direction: row instead. How can I in the same time keep the blue text truncation with ellipsis and the flex-wrap: wrap property behaviour?


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', 
  () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.entity-container')]
    .map(item => item.style.minWidth != '' ? 
    item.style.minWidth = '' : 
    item.style.minWidth = 0)
  })
.monitored-entities {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.entity-title {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;         
}
.entity-container {
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: initial;
}
.entity-container > span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
}
.entity-variables div {
  display: flex;
}
<div style='max-width: 400px'>
  <button>Toggle element min-width</button>
  <div class="monitored-entities">
    <div class="entity-container" style="">
      <span class="entity-title">host.webdata.replica.123456789.123456789.123456789</span>
      <div class='entity-variables'>
        <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Bad</span></div>                                 
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="entity-container">
      <span class="entity-title">db.webdata.source</span>
      <div class='entity-variables'>
        <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Good</span></div>                                    
      </div>
    </div>              
    <div class="entity-container">
      <span class="entity-title">db.webdata.replica</span>
      <div class='entity-variables'>
        <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Bad</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
</div>




min-width: 0 does not break the flex-wrap: wrap property of .monitored-entities. The issue you're encountering is caused by nested flex containers, where the child container (.entity-variables div) lacks flex-wrap: wrap.
To fix this, you have two options:

Remove the nested flex container (.entity-variables div).
Add flex-wrap: wrap to the nested flex container to allow its content to wrap correctly.

Here’s how you can apply the second option:


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
  () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.entity-container')]
      .map(item => item.style.minWidth != '' ?
        item.style.minWidth = '' :
        item.style.minWidth = 0)
  })
.monitored-entities {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.entity-title {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.entity-container {
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: initial;
}
.entity-container > span {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
}
.entity-variables div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  <div style='max-width: 400px'>
    <button>Toggle element min-width</button>
    <div class="monitored-entities">
      <div class="entity-container">
        <span class="entity-title">host.webdata.replica.123456789.123456789.123456789</span>
        <div class='entity-variables'>
          <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Bad</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="entity-container">
        <span class="entity-title">db.webdata.source</span>
        <div class='entity-variables'>
          <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Good</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="entity-container">
        <span class="entity-title">db.webdata.replica</span>
        <div class='entity-variables'>
          <div><span class="variable-name"> health: </span><span>Bad</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



